# Arrays stringing numbers

Tags: java, arrays

```
package javaapplication1;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] scores = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int[] fin = extractAllEvens(scores);
        for(int i =0; i<fin.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(fin[i]);
    }
    }
        public static int[] extractAllEvens(int[]scores) {
            int evenCount = 0;
            for (int i =0; i<scores.length; i++) {
                if (scores[i] % 2 ==0) {
                    evenCount++;
                }
        }
        int[] newScores = new int[evenCount];
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<scores.length; i++) {

            if(scores[1] % 2 ==0) {
            newScores[1] = scores[i];
            j++;
            }
        }
    return newScores;
}
}
```

I'm trying to output 2, 4, 6.

But I keep getting results such as 0,6,0.

I think I messed up somewhere with the variables with i or j or the number 1 and possibly their locations... can anyone help lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

`scores[1] % 2 == 0` and `newScores[1] = scores[i]`?

You have hard-coded to use only index `1` (the second element) of `newArray`.

You probably should be using `j` as the index instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your last loop uses 1 as fixed loop index.

Change that to *i* instead.

Comment: ummm one should be i and other one  j :)

Comment: You are right. And the real take away us:the op should try writing less confusing code in the first place :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change the  second for loop like this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] % 2 == 0) {
            newScores[j] = scores[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if(scores[1] % 2 ==0) {
        newScores[1] = scores[i];
```

It should be

```
if(scores[i] % 2 ==0) {//← i here
        newScores[j] = scores[i];//← j here
```

O/P : 2 4 6